# Cart Breaks on getProductThumbnail

Tags: addtocart, session, shopping-cart, mini-cart, vagrant

I created a local dev instance of my site. The site layout breaks on dev after I add items to cart.

After clicking Add to Cart, the loader spins for a couple seconds and disappears without showing the confirmation popup. The mini-cart doesn't update to until I refresh the page. Then the mini-cart shows the added item, but the page doesn't load beyond the call to getProductThumbnail. The same problem is on the shopping cart page. The grid and title of the first item load, but the html is broken beyond the opening quote of the image (e.g. <img src=" ).

I have tried setting sessions to both files and db. I am not using secure urls on dev. What am I missing?

Edit: This is a Vagrant box. I briefly resolved the issue by moving the var folder to a shared folder above the Magento root folder and creating a symlink (ln -s ../shared/var/ var). I tested adding to cart and logging into back end--all good--but when I came back later, I once again had the same problem with the Add to Cart confirmation not displaying and the page layout broken at the call to getProductThumbnail.

Comment: How is your local dev instance configured? Vagrant? Just a VM in VirtualBox, VMWare Fusion? Otherwise, this sounds like a permissions issue and these things are important in providing a potential solution.

Comment: It's Vagrant on VirtualBox. I actually had a permission problem with var/session and was unable to log in to admin. Setting session save location to /tmp/session resolved that issue.

Comment: I would try setting your Vagrantfile to mount the folder you're working out of as owned by your apache user (www-data, apache, whatever it may be). This has usually fixed it for me in the past.

Comment: It's owned by www-data with 777 permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading Magento from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.3 resolved the issue.